# When installing pycurl on Windows I get, "Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl"

Tags: python, curl, environment-variables, pip, pycurl

Trying to install the python library pycurl on my Windows machine. I already have pip set up so I'm using the command, "pip install pycurl". However I get this in the error logs -

```
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
```

I tried using the --curl-dir tag but it is not recognized.

Comment: Why don't you use windows built [libraries](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/download/). Maybe simpler !

Comment: It has crashed every time I try to run the run the executable. Maybe because I have a 64 bit versions of Windows?

Comment: This question has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58847770/10146012)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using urllib2 library instead which I installed onto my machine with zero issues.