# Having trouble installing pycurl on windows

Tags: python, windows, pycurl

I'm having trouble getting pycurl installed on my windows computer.
At first I tried pip, but ran into the “Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl” error, and have since tried installing curl before running it again.

I downloaded curl from http://curl.haxx.se/download.html and have extracted it into it's own folder.

I tried the following:

```
D:\Downloads\pycurl-7.19.5.1\pycurl-7.19.5.1>python setup.py install --curl-dir="D:\Downloads\curl-7.40.0\curl-7.40.0"
```

But received the following error.

```
Using curl directory: D:\Downloads\curl-7.40.0\curl-7.40.0
libcurl.lib does not exist at D:\Downloads\curl-7.40.0\curl-7.40.0\lib\libcurl.lib.
Curl directory must point to compiled libcurl (bin/include/lib subdirectories):
```

I can't find this libcurl.lib file that it's looking for.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

Have re-downloaded a new library from the same website, curl-7.40.0-win64, which contains a libcurl.lib file.

```
D:\Downloads\pycurl-7.19.5.1\pycurl-7.19.5.1>python setup.py install --curl-dir=
"D:\Downloads\curl-7.40.0-win64\curl-7.40.0-win64\"
Curl directory does not exist: D:\Downloads\curl-7.40.0-win64\curl-7.40.0-win64"


D:\Downloads\pycurl-7.19.5.1\pycurl-7.19.5.1>python setup.py install --curl-dir=
"D:\Downloads\curl-7.40.0-win64\curl-7.40.0-win64\lib"
Using curl directory: D:\Downloads\curl-7.40.0-win64\curl-7.40.0-win64\lib
libcurl.lib does not exist at D:\Downloads\curl-7.40.0-win64\curl-7.40.0-win64\l
ib\lib\libcurl.lib.
Curl directory must point to compiled libcurl (bin/include/lib subdirectories):
D:\Downloads\curl-7.40.0-win64\curl-7.40.0-win64\lib

D:\Downloads\pycurl-7.19.5.1\pycurl-7.19.5.1>
```

Comment: I downloaded curl-7.40.0-win64 and it definitely has libcurl.lib present in its lib directory. Might you need to download it again?

Comment: @PaulRooney I re-downloaded the file you described, extracted and tried again. See my edit.

Comment: Can you  download the `pycurl` wheel file for your `python` version and try installing it with `pip`

Comment: I have given an anwer here  to a different question but it fits here too. In short find the windows installer for a higher package and then downgrade. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47888757/importerror-pycurl-libcurl-link-time-ssl-backend-openssl-is-different-from-c/69461885#69461885

Answer (score 9):

Another simple way to resolve the problem is to use [Christoph Gohlke](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/)'s collection of [Python Extension Package for Windows](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs).

**Steps**

1. Visit the link above and use `Ctrl+F` and search for `pycurl`, or
   [use this link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pycurl) to directly go to the `pycurl` binaries
2. Download the relevant PycURL version. Remember that the PycURL version in the file name must match the version in your `requirements.txt` file (if you're using one), and `cpXXX` needs to match your version of Python (thanks @d6stringer)
3. Copy the file to your working directory and then `pip install` that file e.g. `pip install .\pycurl-7.43.0.5-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl` (thanks @jlr)
4. Re-run `pip install -r requirements.txt` or whatever command you were running

Comment: This was the easiest for me, everyone on Windows should give this a try. Example:
`pip install .\pycurl-7.43.0.5-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl`. And then it's done.

Comment: Magical thank you! Worth noting that cpXXX is the version of python you're using.

Comment: Second time I've found this answer! I took the opportunity to explicitly write out the steps to further help others (and future-me) when this answer pops up again

Answer (score 8):

It is frustrating how much time I spent looking for a solution to this problem on internet, and finally found all my answers in the official pycurl [website](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/install.html)

In my arch Linux system I have no problem installing `pycurl`, but found all this hassle when trying to install `pycurl` on windows using `pip`, giving errors:

```
“Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl” error
```

and trying to fix this error with same steps as in "op" question and getting exact errors.

.

**Solution for windows:**

**[EDIT]** Unfortunately, option 1 below doesn't work anymore, the link for binaries is down, and reference removed from `pycurl` documentation.

1- the easy way is to download a ready made official packages, zip, exe, or msi, as mentioned [here](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/install.html#official-packages), official downloads from [here](https://dl.bintray.com/pycurl/pycurl/). Make sure to choose the link with the same version of your installed python.

For example: [pycurl-7.43.0.2.win-amd64-py3.6.exe](https://dl.bintray.com/pycurl/pycurl/:pycurl-7.43.0.2.win-amd64-py3.6.exe) is an installer for pycurl 7.43.0.2 on windows 64bit, with python 3.6 installed

2- The hard way: [Building From Source](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/install.html#building-from-source), as quoted from their website, is not a good idea to do so but still possible,

> Building PycURL from source is not for the faint of heart due to the multitude of possible dependencies and each of these dependencies having its own directory structure, configuration style, parameters and quirks. Additionally different dependencies have different settings for MSVCRT usage, and an application must have all of its parts agreeing on a single setting.

If you continue reading [here](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/install.html#building-from-source) you will find a detailed instructions how to build from source

Finally, I recommend using a ready made package which I think it should be made available to be automatically installed by pip and avoid all this hassle.

Comment: Step 1 - this is the best answer! It's annoying that pyCurl-Homepage says you should be able to install on Windows using PIP when this is clearly not the case.

Comment: The setup exe will work for the main python install, however for a virtual environment, such as pipenv, it will not work. In that case Yuan Ji's answer works well.

Comment: When I install with the msi installer, I can't import pycurl

Comment: bintray dows not exist anymore

Comment: @BlueClouds, sadly this is right, will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `pycurl` package on the [website](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/), the execute the command:

```
pip install xx\xx\pycurl-xx.whl
```

to install `pycurl`

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

```
pip install pycurl==7.43.0.5
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to download sources and build it by yourself: as result you will have to get directories like:

- libcurl-vc12-x86-release-dll-ipv6-sspi-winssl

  - bin

    - curl.exe
    - libcurl.dll
  - include

    - *.h
  - lib

    - libcurl.lib

(or you can search for prebuilt binaries/headers with same directory structure)
And then you have to point your setup.py script this directory, such as:

```
python setup.py install --curl-dir="D:\..\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-dll-ipv6-sspi-winssl
```

And it will be built successfully.

Comment: I tried to build it.

Just gave up and remade the project using Requests.