# ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backend (openssl) is different from compile-time ssl backend (none/other)

Tags: python, pycurl

I wanted to run python file. But I could check this error when I ran it.

ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backend (openssl) is different from compile-time ssl backend (none/other)

My system is Mac os 10.13.2 and I used python 2.7

Answer (score 38):

Looks like something went wrong with pycurl/openssl, try this:

```
pip uninstall pycurl
pip install --compile --install-option="--with-openssl" pycurl
```

if still fails, try this as well

```
brew reinstall openssl
```

Comment: Thank you for your kindness!! FInally I could make it!

Comment: running `brew reinstall openssl` was required on an upgraded macOS 10.13 machine

Comment: how the heck did you know this solution (compile with ssl)? Thx!

Comment: +1, thanks. Anyone have any idea how I can install with poetry? `poetry add pycurl` doesn't seem to give the option of supplying flags.

Comment: On a macOS 12.3, after `brew reinstall openssl` you can run `brew info openssl` and it will tell you some environment variables you need to set for the pycurl install to work.

Comment: I had to find the path to openssl via `brew info openssl` and pass it to pip: `pip install --compile --install-option="--with-openssl" --install-option="--openssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/" pycurl`

Comment: On a mac M1 with a recent version of pip, I used the following successfully:
`pip install --compile --config-settings="--build-option=--with-openssl --openssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/" pycurl `

Answer (score 16):

This was done by my fellow mac users.

```
# pycurl
pip uninstall pycurl
export CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include # may be needed
export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib # may be needed
pip install --no-cache-dir --compile --ignore-installed --install-option="--with-openssl" pycurl
```

---

I got this same issue in windows which had a different fix(perhaps this might fit Mac too). In my requirements.txt I had `pycurl-7.43.0.4` but on the [windows dowloader page](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pycurl) I could only find `7.44.1` which I installed (`pip install .\pycurl-7.44.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`). And then on starting my Django server `python manage.py runserver` I got the error in question. And the solution was to bring the pycurl back to it's expected version. `pip install pycurl==7.43.0.5` and it replaced the version as given below. And the error was gone!
[image]

Comment: This fix worked for me. The flags needed to be specified on OSX Montarey

Comment: Accepted answer did not work for me. This one did!

Answer (score 11):

How I resolve this issue on my Mac Book Pro M1 (Chip Apple M1 Pro).

I am using system provided Python 3.9.6 as MacOs Monterey 12.6 completely removed Python 2.7 and providing Python 3.9.6 as system Python.

two thing is very important to know curl info by using

1. `curl-config --features`
2. `brew openssl info`

this gives you information according to your own machine setup for using in below installation to use.

In my case it was

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include"
```

For pkg-config to find openssl@3 you may need to set:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib/pkgconfig"
```

```
pip install --no-cache-dir --compile --ignore-installed --install-option="--with-openssl" pycurl
```

it was done!!! perfectly.

Alternatively, if you get an error saying

```
no such option: --install-option
```

You can try:

```
env PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include" pip install --no-cache-dir --compile --ignore-installed pycurl
```

and it should work!

Answer (score 8):

For m1 users, it works for me

```
brew install curl-openssl
pip uninstall pycurl

PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl \
    LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" \
    CPPFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" 

pip install --compile --install-option="--with-openssl" pycurl
```

Comment: I had to add `--use-pep517` in addition:
```pip install --no-cache-dir --ignore-installed --compile --install-option="--with-openssl" pycurl --use-pep517```

Comment: `--install-option` is not an option for later versions of pip

Answer (score 7):

Setup: MacOS Ventura, M1, Python 3.9, pip 23.1.2

**With pip 23.1, `--install-option="..."` is deprecated.**

What worked for me was actually following the installation guide from pycurl: http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/install.html#easy-install-pip

```
pip3 uninstall pycurl  
brew install curl-openssl
export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl
pip3 install --no-cache-dir --ignore-installed --compile pycurl
```

Answer (score 2):

Reinstall the curl libraries

```
brew install curl --with-openssl
```

Install pycurl with correct environment and paths

```
export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl
pip uninstall pycurl 
pip install --no-cache-dir --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" --global-option="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"  pycurl
```

Comment: Error: `invalid option: --with-openssl`

Answer (score 0):

On macOS Catalina (v10.15.6), make sure you uninstall previous `curl` then install `curl-openssl` as well as exporting variables so compiler can find them:

```
brew uninstall curl
brew install curl-openssl

export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl
export PYCURL_CURL_CONFIG=/usr/local/opt/curl-openssl/bin/curl-config;export LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/c-ares/lib -L/usr/local/opt/nghttp2/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libmetalink/lib -L/usr/local/opt/rtmpdump/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libssh2/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openldap/lib -L/usr/local/opt/brotli/lib';export CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include;pip install pycurl --compile --no-cache-dir

pip install pycurl
```

Comment: This works for me, but for my case, the install command requires one more flag:  `ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" pip install pycurl --compile --no-cache-dir`

Comment: For me on BigSur (11.2.3) with a M1:

     `export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl
     export PYCURL_CURL_CONFIG=/opt/homebrew/opt/curl/bin/curl-config
     export LDFLAGS='-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/lib/'
     export CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/include
     pip install pycurl --compile --no-cache-dir
`

Answer (score 0):

I am running MacOS Ventura on my MacBook Pro.
We use Python 3.7. The following worked for me:

```
% python3.7 -m pip uninstall pycurl
% brew install curl
% brew install openssl

% export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/curl/lib $LDFLAGS"
% export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/curl/include $CPPFLAGS"
% export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/curl/lib/pkgconfig

% python3.7 -m pip install pycurl==7.45.2 --no-cache-dir --compile --ignore-installed --install-option="--openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/"
```