# Installing pycurl on MacOS. (link-time ssl backend (none/other) is different from compile-time ssl backend (openssl))

Tags: openssl, macos-sierra, pycurl

I'm trying to install pycurl in a venv on MacOS Sierra.  I've cleaned things up, installed openssl via brew, told pip to link to that openssl installation and tried loading the module.  It complains about "none/other" being different from "openssl".

```
ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backend (none/other) is different from compile-time ssl backend (openssl)
```

It seems the package was compiled as expected but it's trying to load the wrong ssl library.  Any suggestions on addressing this?  I've tried google search after google search.

The full installation attempt:

```
(venv) R5106464:venv m106093$ brew uninstall openssl
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/openssl
(venv) R5106464:venv m106093$ pip uninstall pycurl
Skipping pycurl as it is not installed.
(venv) R5106464:venv m106093$ brew install openssl
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/openssl-1.0.2q.sierra.bottl
Already downloaded: /Users/m106093/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/b6dec2b57ee88a3cb02335284971b3b1e902d8b43fef115b456a971e5d0981ce--openssl-1.0.2q.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring openssl-1.0.2q.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
A CA file has been bootstrapped using certificates from the SystemRoots
keychain. To add additional certificates (e.g. the certificates added in
the System keychain), place .pem files in
  /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs

and run
  /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/c_rehash

openssl is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because Apple has deprecated use of OpenSSL in favor of its own TLS and crypto libraries.

If you need to have openssl first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find openssl you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"

For pkg-config to find openssl you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig"

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2q: 1,794 files, 12.3MB
(venv) R5106464:venv m106093$ PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" pip install --no-cache-dir pycurl
Collecting pycurl
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e8/e4/0dbb8735407189f00b33d84122b9be52c790c7c3b25286826f4e1bdb7bde/pycurl-7.43.0.2.tar.gz (214kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 215kB 3.6MB/s 
Installing collected packages: pycurl
  Running setup.py install for pycurl ... done
Successfully installed pycurl-7.43.0.2
(venv) R5106464:venv m106093$ python
Python 2.7.10 (v2.7.10:15c95b7d81dc, May 23 2015, 09:33:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pycurl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backend (none/other) is different from compile-time ssl backend (openssl)
>>>
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47888757/importerror-pycurl-libcurl-link-time-ssl-backend-openssl-is-different-from-c?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backend (openssl) is different from compile-time ssl backend (none/other)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47888757/importerror-pycurl-libcurl-link-time-ssl-backend-openssl-is-different-from-c)

Answer (score 2):

hello i have this problem whit python 3.8 in Mac OS Mojave I solve from:

```
sudo -H pip uninstall pycurl

brew install openssl

PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl

pip install --no-cache-dir --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" --global-option="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" --user pycurl
```

and now is working PycURL

Comment: For Mac Ventura 13.2.1 and Homebrew 4.0.10 I had change the above to below:        
 `pip install --no-cache-dir --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/lib" --global-option="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/include" --user pycurl`