# How to install a package with Poetry that requires CLI args?

Tags: installation, pip, pycurl, python-poetry

Here's an example that requires it:

```
poetry add pycurl
```

... gives:
[ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backend (openssl) is different from compile-time ssl backend (none/other)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47888757/importerror-pycurl-libcurl-link-time-ssl-backend-openssl-is-different-from-c)

The fix is given in that post:

```
pip install --compile --install-option="--with-openssl" pycurl
```

How to package-manage my project now?

Must I use `poetry` for everything else, and manually `pip install` pycurl?

Or can I somehow fold it into my `pyproject.toml`?

Comment: the only related discussion I could find was this one: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/pull/2017, seems like as of yet there is no support

Answer (score 1):

Although this is old, I would like to share an alternative to re-install the package with the CLI options.

I do not know if running this with Poetry could cause any damage, but I would believe not.

First you'd have to activate your poetry environment with `poetry shell`.
After that, get the current version of `pycurl` that is installed using `pip list`, and copy that value.

Now, you can run `pip install --compile --install-option="--with-openssl" --upgrade --force-reinstall pycurl==<version>` to install it with the correct options.