# unable to install pycurl on windows for Py 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.7, pycurl

In my requirments file there is `pycurl==7.43.0.6`. I am using `Python 3.7`. I get the following error:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 10:
     command: 'c:\python\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\THEMIL~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vqp6dg8i\\pycurl\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\T
HEMIL~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vqp6dg8i\\pycurl\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code,
__file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: C:\Users\THEMIL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vqp6dg8i\pycurl\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 10: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Apparent duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58847770/15452601

Comment: The easiest solution might be download a prebuilt binary for Windows, as in the answer @2e0byo is linking to. The exact version you are trying to install `pycurl==7.43.0.6` might not be available, but I suspect that your application will work with a different version of pycurl.

Answer (score 1):

> Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl

Pycurl is a wrapper around `libcurl`, but you either haven't installed it, or haven't told `pycurl` where to find it.  You need to do so.

Sadly building libcurl on windows doesn't appear to be massively documented: you can either figure it out, or drop the use of `pycurl` and use some other library (e.g. requests) to do the work `pycurl` was doing.  Or you could use a *nix.

Comment: where would we specify this ? in the requirements file `pycurl==7.43.0.6 --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl` ?

Comment: pip install has no such `--curl-dir` parameter

Comment: yes, you have to use setup.py directly as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58847770/15452601).  But see the linked question above.  Or mess with `--install-option` to pass args through to the installer